# In Streaming XSSFWorkbook auto sizing column width using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

We have a large excel file to generate using apache poi and java. In that we want to auto size columns width based on highest length text. We are using following two functions. At the start of the excel generation we are calling

```
sheet.trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing();
```

At the end we are calling following function

```
sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);
```

At the end of the day it is working. But it is taking 3 minutes to generate 100k rows data workbook. Before using above set of functions we were able to generate in 15 seconds.

We are using following constructor to create the workbook object

```
SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(new XSSFWorkbook(), 50000, false, true);
```

Please help us if there are ways to reduce the time taken in auto sizing column.

Comment: Auto size the column after only populating a few hundred rows, and hope you don't have any super-long cells towards the end of the file?

Comment: Loop through the columns and call `autoSizeColumn(int index)` on them. From the docs `Tracks all columns in the sheet for auto-sizing. If this is called, individual columns do not need to be tracked. Because determining the best-fit width for a cell is expensive, this may affect the performance.`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I don't need to call autoSizeColumn for all the columns. So I don't need to loop through the columns. I am doing in following manner

`sheet.autoSizeColumn(1);
sheet.autoSizeColumn(3);
sheet.autoSizeColumn(4);`

Excel is auto generated, so columns comes dynamically. I need to call sheet.trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing(); because not knowing where 1,3 or 4 lies.

Comment: Please avoid using words like *lakh* that are not globally understood